# Convergence of metric implies convergence of eigenvalues?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

Consider the metric $g_\varepsilon=d\theta^2 + \varepsilon^2 \sin(\theta)^2 \, d\varphi^2$ on the hemisphere $S^2_+.$ I had two naive questions:

- Does $g_\varepsilon$ converge to the flat metric on the interval $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ as $\varepsilon\to 0\text{?}$
- Do the eigenfunctions $\lambda_k(-\Delta_{g_\varepsilon})\to \lambda_k([0,\pi]),$ where $\lambda_k$ are Neumann eigenvalues and $\lambda_k([0,\pi])$ denotes the eigenvalues on the interval $[0,\pi]\text{?}$

Comment: $\bar g$ is not a Riemannian metric. How do you define its Laplace operator?

Comment: i meant the flat metric on the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: You mean convergence in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense?